# Creating a Python Package That Adds Script to Path

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python package, and I'd like to add a script to the users PATH once they install it. I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology, so here's an example of what I'd like to accomplish:

1. user installs package via pip

```
pip install my-pkg
```

2. once installed the user can enter the following in their termial

```
my-pkg start
```

3. this then creates a settings.py/index.html files in the current dir

This is similar to running `django-admin startproject`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by specifying that script in your `setup.py` as an [entrypoint](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html).

If using a pyproject.toml, the equivalent is a [plugin](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#plugins).

Comment: ... if OP is using setup.py... This is done in other ways in other tools (for example poetry's pyproject.toml)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @Ray Johns answer, this is what it would look like inside your `setuptools.setup` function.

```
entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'command = my-pkg.module:func',                  
        ], 
}
```